# PyQt5 Drawing over image with semi transparent color

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to draw over image using QPainter. It works good when using solid color. When using semi transparent color, dots were appearing.

Also when drawing multiple lines in one place, the color gets multiplied and produces a darker color.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor


class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = False
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.image = QPixmap(r"C:\Users\www\Desktop\image.jpg")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(121,252,50,50), 20, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainMenu = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

I need to keep the color as the original color(instead of getting darker each time) when drawing several times over the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouse movement are "discrete", which means that whenever you move your mouse you won't get continuous pixel coordinates: if you move your mouse fast enough from `(0, 0)` to `(20, 20)`, you'll probably get only two or three mouseMoveEvents in the middle at most, resulting in single segments for each mouse event.
The "dots" you see are actually areas where the different lines you draw collide, expecially since the mouse movement are not continuous. If you think of it as painting with watercolors, it's like if you draw a small line at each mouse movement, then wait until it's dried, then start to paint another line from the previous point.

As soon as you draw *unique* lines at each mouseMoveEvent, the edges of those segments are superimposed, resulting in those "less transparent dots" (since you're using a non opaque color), which are the points where the segments collide, and, because painting is usually "additive" you get two or more areas where the superimposed color results in a more opaque one: imagine it as watching through *two* pairs of sunglasses that are not aligned.

[`QPainterPath`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html), instead, can draw continuous lines without that "artifact", as long as they are part of the ***same** painter path* (no matter its subpath, including subpath polygons, ellipses, arcs, etc.). Then, whenever you tell the QPainter to draw a *new* element, it will be superimposed to the previous ones.
To better clarify, in this image on the left I'm drawing two distinct lines with a common vertex, using your color, which would be the case of a mousePressEvent (start drawing), a *fast* movement to the right (draw the first line) and another one to the bottom (draw another line). On the right there are the same "lines", but using a unique QPainterPath.

[image: common vertex lines]

In this example code I temporarily create a painter path, which stores the current "drawing path" until the mouse is released, after which the path is actually applied to the QPixmap.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor, QPainterPath


class Menu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawingPath = None
        self.image = QPixmap(r"testimage.jpg")
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)
        if self.drawingPath:
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(121,252,50,50), 20, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawPath(self.drawingPath)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # start a new QPainterPath and *move* to the current point
            self.drawingPath = QPainterPath()
            self.drawingPath.moveTo(event.pos())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawingPath:
            # add a line to the painter path, without "removing" the pen
            self.drawingPath.lineTo(event.pos())
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.drawingPath:
            # draw the painter path to the pixmap
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(121,252,50,50), 20, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawPath(self.drawingPath)
            self.drawingPath = None
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainMenu = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There is only one problem with this: drawing *over* a **currently** drawing path won't result in a more opaque color, meaning that, as long as the mouse button is pressed, no matter how many times you "paint" over the same point, the color will always be the same. To get the "more opaque color" effect, you'll need to paint over the intersection(s), starting a new path each time.

PS: I used a QWidget, as in some cases a QMainWindow can grab mouse movements starting from a click on a non interactive area (like in this case) and use it to move the interface.

Comment: QPainterPath works perfect and produces continuous line without segments. Is there any way to avoid additive color (more opaque) in places where several lines intersect each other?

Comment: @Vaas only if they're part of the same QPainterPath.

Comment: @Vaas I edited the answer, clarifying that additive coloring actually comes in place whenever the painter draws a *new* element: if you've different elements of the same QPainterPath (as in subpaths, such as polygons or ellipses) there won't be any color superimposition, while that happens if you paint them as distinct elements (such as using `QPainterPath.toSubpathPolygons`). I think that it *might* be possible by setting the right [`QPainter.CompositionMode`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) but I've always found its behavior difficult to understand.